# Помогите переделать или внедрить код Razor Pages в MVC проект

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Нашел подходящее решение для осуществления авторизации на сайте через Telegram, но выполненное в виде Razor Pages. Пробовал внедрить, но постоянно получаю пустую модель, т.к. не понимаю работу Razor Pages (переделать код тоже не вышло, не понимаю как создать такую модель для страницы). Времени на изучение и переделывание MVC проекта не хватает. Если есть рабочий вариант внедрения в MVC, хотелось бы поподробнее узнать об этом.

Собственно сам код:

TelegramLogin.cshtml

```
@page
@model Cackle.Identity.Telegram.UI.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.TelegramLoginModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div style="align-items: center; display: flex; justify-content: center; min-height: 75vh;">
    <div style="width: 128px;">
        <img src="/telegramLogin/t_logo_2x.png" alt="Telegram Logo" width="128" height="128"/>
        <img src="/telegramLogin/Telegram_1x.png" alt="Telegram Header" width="128" height="36" style="margin: 18px auto;">
    </div>
    <div style="border-left: 5px solid #179cde; margin: 50px; padding: 25px;">
        <partial name="TelegramLoginWidget" model="@Model.WidgetModel"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

TelegramLogin.cshtml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Cackle.Identity.Telegram.UI.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class TelegramLoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly TelegramLoginWidgetOptions _widgetOptions;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Populated WidgetModel provided to the page.
        /// </summary>
        public TelegramLoginWidgetModel WidgetModel;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Provides <see cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions" /> to the page.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="widgetOptions">TelegramLoginWidgetOptions provided by DI.</param>
        public TelegramLoginModel(IOptionsMonitor<TelegramLoginWidgetOptions> widgetOptions)
        {
            _widgetOptions = widgetOptions.CurrentValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Passes Telegram Login Widget to the page to be used by the <see cref="TelegramLoginWidgetModel" /> partial page.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="redirectUri">Incoming URL parameter to pass to through to HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync.</param>
        /// <param name="state">Incoming URL parameter generated by HandleChallengeAsync.</param>
        public void OnGet(string redirectUri = null, string state = null)
        {
            redirectUri ??= _widgetOptions.CallbackPath;
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"state", state}
            };

            _widgetOptions.CallbackPath = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(redirectUri, parameters);

            // Create the TelegramLoginWidgetModel here to be elegantly passed to the partial page.
            WidgetModel = TelegramLoginWidgetModel.Configure(_widgetOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

TelegramLoginWidget.cshtml

```
@using Cackle.Identity.Telegram.UI
@model Cackle.Identity.Telegram.UI.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.TelegramLoginWidgetModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<script async="@true"
        src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?15"
        data-telegram-login="@Model.BotUserName"
        data-size="@Model.ButtonStyle"
        @{
            if (!Model.ShowUserPhoto)
            {
                <text> data-userpic="false" </text>
            }
        }
        @{
            if (Model.CornerRadius != -1)
            {
                <text> data-radius="@Model.CornerRadius" </text>
            }
        }
        @{
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.RedirectUrl))
            {
                <text> data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user, origin)" </text>
            }
        }
        @{
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.RedirectUrl))
            {
                <text> @Model.RedirectUrl </text>
            }
        }
        @{
            if (Model.SendMessageAccess)
            {
                <text> data-request-access="write" </text>
            }
        }></script>
<form method="post" id="telegramLogin" action="@Model.CallbackPath">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" name="@TelegramLoginWidgetConstants.UserDataField" id="userData"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="@TelegramLoginWidgetConstants.OriginField" id="origin"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onTelegramAuth(user, origin) {
        document.getElementById("userData").value = btoa(JSON.stringify(user));
        document.getElementById("origin").value = origin;
        document.getElementById("telegramLogin").submit();
    }
</script>
```

TelegramLoginWidget.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Cackle.Identity.Telegram.UI.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class TelegramLoginWidgetModel : PageModel
    {
        public readonly string BotUserName;
        public readonly string ButtonStyle;
        public readonly string CallbackPath;
        public readonly int CornerRadius;
        public readonly string RedirectUrl;
        public readonly bool SendMessageAccess;
        public readonly bool ShowUserPhoto;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Configures <paramref cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions" />
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="botUserName">
        ///     <inheritdoc cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions.BotUserName" />
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="callbackPath">
        ///     <inheritdoc cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions.CallbackPath" />
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="buttonStyle">
        ///     <inheritdoc cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions.ButtonStyle" />
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="showUserPhoto">
        ///     <inheritdoc cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions.ShowUserPhoto" />
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="cornerRadius">
        ///     <inheritdoc cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions.CornerRadius" />
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="redirectUrl">
        ///     <inheritdoc cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions.RedirectUrl" />
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="sendMessageAccess">
        ///     <inheritdoc cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions.SendMessageAccess" />
        /// </param>
        public TelegramLoginWidgetModel(string botUserName,
            string callbackPath = TelegramLoginWidgetDefaults.CallbackPath,
            string buttonStyle = TelegramLoginWidgetDefaults.ButtonStyle,
            bool showUserPhoto = TelegramLoginWidgetDefaults.ShowUserPhoto,
            int cornerRadius = TelegramLoginWidgetDefaults.CornerRadius,
            string redirectUrl = TelegramLoginWidgetDefaults.RedirectUrl,
            bool sendMessageAccess = TelegramLoginWidgetDefaults.SendMessageAccess)
        {
            BotUserName = botUserName;
            CallbackPath = callbackPath;
            ButtonStyle = buttonStyle;
            ShowUserPhoto = showUserPhoto;
            CornerRadius = cornerRadius;
            RedirectUrl = redirectUrl;
            SendMessageAccess = sendMessageAccess;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Configures <paramref cref="TelegramLoginWidgetOptions" />
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="widgetOptions">Allows manually configuring the Telegram Login widget.</param>
        public TelegramLoginWidgetModel(TelegramLoginWidgetOptions widgetOptions)
        {
            BotUserName = widgetOptions.BotUserName;
            CallbackPath = widgetOptions.CallbackPath;
            ButtonStyle = widgetOptions.ButtonStyle;
            ShowUserPhoto = widgetOptions.ShowUserPhoto;
            CornerRadius = widgetOptions.CornerRadius;
            RedirectUrl = widgetOptions.RedirectUrl;
            SendMessageAccess = widgetOptions.SendMessageAccess;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Convenience method to configure model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="widgetOptions" />
        /// <returns>An instance of this object.</returns>
        public static TelegramLoginWidgetModel Configure(TelegramLoginWidgetOptions widgetOptions)
        {
            return new(widgetOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот откуда взял: https://github.com/mrUlrik/Cackle.Identity.Telegram/tree/main/Cackle.Identity.Telegram.UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Встроить Razor Pages в MVC оказалось не так трудно:

1. Иерархия проекта:

[image: В корень проекта добавляется папка Page в которой и будут храниться страницы razor page]

2. Настройка Layout для Page, который будет браться из /Views/Shared/_Layout.chtml (Файл _ViewStart.chtml):

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

3. Добавление строк в Sturtup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllers();

            ...
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            ...
        }
```

4. Переход с View на Page:

```
<a asp-page="/TelegramLogin">Telegram Login</a>
```